# creating an array in the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create this structure:

```
qBank: [
      {
        question: "what number?",
        answers: ["100", "200", "300", "400"],
        correct: "100",
        id: 0,

      },
```

it does not work

```
 appendQuestion = (Quest,A,B,C,D,Good) => {
    this.setState({
      qBank: ([...this.state.qBank,{Quest,[A,B,C,D],Good}])
    })
  }
```

Comment: Where's the data you make the structure form? Can you provide sample input, and expected/actual output?

Comment: Does not work in what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{Quest,[A,B,C,D],Good}` is not a correct syntax to create an  object.

Try

```js
qBank: ([...this.state.qBank, {
  question: Quest,
  answers: [A, B, C, D],
  correct: Good
}])
```